# Excel Count Distinct

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: Excel Spreadsheet]

Trying to count distinct based on 2 parameters and values. It works with 1 parameter but not with 2. I am trying to sum up the number of reports ran for the following years and months. The first is for the year and the second is for the month. The columns are all correct.

Version 2305 Build 16

Formula

```
{=SUM(IF(bpt!$E$2:$E$15008='Cover Page'!$B10,(1/COUNTIFS(bpt!$C$2:$C$15008,bpt!$C$2:$C$15008,bpt!$E$2:$E$15008,bpt!$E$2:$E$15008)),0))}
```

Just played with the formula and nothing has appeared to fix the issue.

Mockup of data

[image: Mockup Data]

Comment: What is expected result? H11 = 6 and C10 = 2 with given data?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this way, it works on my end,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>H2</kbd>

```
=SUMPRODUCT((($G2=$E$2:$E$9)*(H$1=$D$2:$D$9))/
COUNTIFS($D$2:$D$9,$D$2:$D$9,$E$2:$E$9,$E$2:$E$9,$C$2:$C$9,$C$2:$C$9))
```

---

Note: Please change the cell references and ranges as per your suit.

---

If one has access to **`MS365`** could use the following formula as well.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>H2</kbd>

```
=IFERROR(SUM(--(UNIQUE(FILTER($C$2:$C$9,($G2=$E$2:$E$9)*(H$1=$D$2:$D$9)))<>"")),"")
```

---

Again, please change the cell reference and ranges accordingly as per your data.

---

May be there is more elegant way of using this to have a dynamic spill, but I tried in this way, using <kbd>MAKEARRAY( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>H2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     _years,G2:G3,
     _months,H1:I1,
     _rmonth,D2:D9,
     _ryear,E2:E9,
     _cnumber,C2:C9,
     MAKEARRAY(ROWS(_years),COLUMNS(_months),LAMBDA(r,c,
              SUM(--(UNIQUE(FILTER(_cnumber,(_ryear=INDEX(_years,r))*
              (_rmonth=INDEX(_months,c)),""))<>"")))))
```

---